# Error When Double Unpacking Number

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have some code that looks like:

```
import struct

def Get_Float(paintwear):
    buf = struct.pack('i', paintwear)
    item_float = struct.unpack('f', buf)[0]
    return item_float

paintwear = 1033975072
item_float = Get_Float(paintwear)
print(item_float)
```

This works and gives me item_float as 0.07871460914611816. However, I am trying to get that number to be more specific by double unpacking it like this:

```
import struct

def Get_Float(paintwear):
    buf = struct.pack('i', paintwear)
    item_float = struct.unpack('d', buf)[0]
    return item_float

paintwear = 1033975072
item_float = Get_Float(paintwear)
print(item_float)
```

I changed the f to a d and now I get this error: `struct.error: unpack requires a bytes object of length 8`

Any ideas? Thanks!

Comment: Instead of "Double unpacking" (which sounds like you unpacked twice) how about "unpack as double"?

Comment: It seems straight-forward. `I` packs to 4 bytes. `f` unpacks 4 bytes. But `d` needs 8 bytes. I can't figure out what your goal for this code is, the integer and float don't have anything in common. What is getting a double supposed to do?

Comment: @tdelaney Using the 'f' method, I can get something like 0.007548765745013952, but there is some other method where I can get a float as accurate as 0.09112001210451126099 and 0.13371336460113525391 which is a bit more accurate. For my program, I need these as accurate as possible.

Comment: `f` represents a 32 bit floating point number in binary but is smaller than a python `float` so you'll get rounding. `d` is a 64 bit floating point number and can store python floats without rounding. So, its more accurate if you want to store a `float` somewhere. It makes no sense to do that integer thing you are doing. How does the integer going in have anything to do with the float coming out?

Comment: @tdelaney thanks for your help, but I think the issue was not getting more accurate digits, but that there actually only like 20 digits showing instead of 25

Comment: Its 53 bits in all. See [15. Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/floatingpoint.html)

Comment: @AndersonP: you should be able to do `{:.22f}` to get all the digits in that particular number.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use floating point number formatting:

```
return "{:.22f}".format(item_float)
```

Where `22` is the number of digits returned (or however many required) after the decimal.

Comment: That doesn't change the precision of the float, just how many digits python displays. Not that its a bad thing, but it should be mentioned.

Comment: Thanks! This helps for sure